# How to support node selection when using helm install

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Using helm 2.7.3.  New to helm and kubernetes.  I have two worker nodes, and I want to deploy to a specific node.   I've assigned unique labels to each node.  I then added nodeSelector to deployment.yaml.  When I run helm install it appears to be ignoring the node selection and deploys randomly between the two worker nodes.
Would like to understand the best approach to node selection when deploying with helm.

Comment: Are you using any stable helm/chart? Or, you have made your own chart?

Answer (score 23):

You can use something like this:

```sh
helm install --name elasticsearch elastic/elasticsearch --set \
 nodeSelector."beta\\.kubernetes\\.io/os"=linux
```

Note: Escaping `.` character! Hope this helps.

Comment: what is the first `.` for before `"` ? How do we use custom label like `boardType=xyzNode` ?

Comment: it's called dot notation where you can reference sub key as nodeSelector is map object that contains key/value pairs. in your case

  nodeSelector."boardType"=xyzNode

Answer (score 20):

See the example:

```
kubectl label nodes <your desired node> databases=mysql --overwrite
```

Check the label:

```
kubectl get nodes  --show-labels
```

Run the following command:

```
helm create test-chart && cd test-chart
helm install . --set nodeSelector.databases=mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

in ansible task

```
- name: install etcd middleware
  command:
    chdir: /var/lib/kube/controlpanel/component
    cmd: "{{tools.helm.path}} upgrade etcd ./etcd --install --namespace=middleware --set replicaCount=3 --set nodeSelector.\"xxx\\.yyy\\.local/node-role-middleware\"="
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one example:

> helm upgrade --install airflow apache-airflow/airflow --namespace airflow --create-namespace --set {nodeSelector="**your-worker-node-name**"}

**--set** allows setting for required parameters.
The following link provides the supported parameters of the mentioned example:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/parameters-ref.html#kubernetes

You can set many parameters using many --set. Look at the link:https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_install/. This is the example:

> helm install **--set** foo=bar **--set** foo=newbar  myredis ./redis

Just check that the nodeSelector parameter is supported by your chart.